# .NET removing all spaces when decoding URI

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, uri

I am sending a parameter, from Javascript to .NET. The parameter could contain multiple spaces like 'John [3 spaces here, stackoverflow not showing them] Smith', I need the spaces to stay. However, it looks like the spaces disappear in .NET. In an attempt to fix this, I made sure to encode the URI on client side, and decode it on server side. The code (in VB.NET) looks like this:

```
<AjaxPro.AjaxMethod()> _
Public Function GetSearch(ByVal strValue As String) As String
 strValue = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(strValue)
 ...
End Function
```

Before the `UrlDecode`, `strValue` looks like `John%20%20%20Smith`'. Afterwards it looks like `John Smith`. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

I am using .NET 2.0 Web Forms.

EDIT: following one of the suggestions below I replaced all the spaces with (ampersand)nbsp;. I can see all the spaces when I debug, however, my database is SQL server, for some reason it views regular spaces to be different from  (ampersand)nbsp; spaces, and as a result the query does not return the right values. It took me some time to figure this out because I could not see the difference with the naked eye.

Comment: Are you sure they aren't there? Browsers render runs of multiple spaces as a single space. If you replace the space character with &nbsp; then you should see all of them.

Comment: I don't understand your problem, when I do this code it prints 3 space. Console.WriteLine(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode("John%20%20%20Smith"))

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to resolve the issue in the front-end by replacing all spaces with Non-breaking spaces. I then had to replace the Non-breaking spaces back with regular spaces in my SQL stored procedure (otherwise the query wouldn't work).